# jQuery select option contains AND not contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown with options that look like this :

```
    <select name="decision">
        <option value="">** Select **</option>
        <option value=0>No</option>
        <option value=1>Yes*</option>
    </select>
```

Depending on a prior user selection, either the "Yes" or "No" may have an asterisk next to the text.

I need to find a way to remove the asterisk from the end of either the Yes or No after the onChange event of another field. 
My train of thought was to edit the text of options that contain "*" and DON'T contain "**" and remove the asterisk but I am doing something wrong and am not sure how to make this work.

```
$('[name=decision] option:contains("*"):not:contains("**")').text($.this.text().replace("*",""));
```

I figure I'm either
a) really close and am just missing something minor, or
b) doing something so horribly wrong that I need to switch career fields

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `:not:contains("**")` => `:not(:contains("**"))` I believe?

Comment: I am not very familiar with jQuery but can't you select all options whose value is *not* `null` (this should exclude the `** Select **` option)?

Comment: Olde fashioned fix if you're stuck with the selector: `.replace("**", "#").replace("*", "").replace("#", "**")`

Comment: As per @secan - it doesn't matter if you do `"No".replace("*", "")` so you could apply the replace on all of them except the one you don't want to change.

Comment: You could also check in the callback: `txt.includes("**") ? txt : txt.replace("*", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your specific question is:

```
$('[name=decision] option:contains("*"):not(:contains("**"))').text((_, text) => text.replace("*",""));
```

Live Example:

```js
$("[name=decision]").on("change", function() {
    $('[name=decision] option:contains("*"):not(:contains("**"))').text((_, text) => text.replace("*",""));
});
```

```html
<select name="decision">
    <option value="">** Select **</option>
    <option value=0>No</option>
    <option value=1>Yes*</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The two changes there are:

- `:not(:contains("**"))` instead of `:not:contains("**")`
- Passing a function to [`text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) so `text` can call it, although you could also use

  ```
  const option = $('[name=decision] option:contains("*"):not(:contains("**"))');
  option.text(option.text().replace("*",""));
  ```

That just *removes* the `*`, which is what you seemed to be working on, it doesn't add the `*` to the newly-selected option.

For me it would be simpler with a basic loop that does both:

```js
$("[name=decision]").on("change", function() {
    for (const option of this.options) {
        if (!option.text.endsWith("**")) { // Or `if (option.index > 0) {`
            option.text = option.text.replace("*", "");
            if (option.selected) {
                option.text += "*";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<select name="decision">
    <option value="">** Select **</option>
    <option value=0>No</option>
    <option value=1>Yes*</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you don't want to use `for-of` because you need to support obsolete browsers:

```js
// For obsolete browsers
$("[name=decision]").on("change", function() {
    for (var n = 1; n < this.options.length; ++n) {
        var option = this.options[n];
        option.text = option.text.replace("*", "");
        if (option.selected) {
            option.text += "*";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<select name="decision">
    <option value="">** Select **</option>
    <option value=0>No</option>
    <option value=1>Yes*</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Argh. Yeah, that did it. I had a feeling I was overcomplicating things unnecessarily. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it like this (assuming that `** Select **` will always be the first option):

```js
$('select option:not(:first)').text((_,o)=>o.replace("*",""))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="decision">
   <option value="">** Select **</option>
   <option value=0>No</option>
   <option value=1>Yes*</option>
</select>
<select name="choice">
   <option value="">** Select again **</option>
   <option value=0>No*</option>
   <option value=1>Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: FYI (I didn't know until someone told me) - As of jQuery 3.4, the `:gt` pseudo-class is deprecated https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! You can of course also do it with `:not (:first)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the select values 1,0 does not have any significance then you can change the value of select

```
<select name="decision">
    <option value="">** Select **</option>
    <option value='No'>No</option>
    <option value='Yes'>Yes*</option>
</select>
```

and get selected value instead of selected text

```
$("#decision").val();
```